# Why can’t the amount of «– RAM of the Android virtual device –» be increased?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to increase the amount of RAM of the device from the following 2 paths

**Path one didn’t work:**
Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings

I set IDE max heap size to 4096
Also the values
Gradle daemon max heap size
And
Kotlin daemon max heap size
I set it to 2048, but it automatically returns to unknown-current mode

**And the second route I tried:**
Virtual device manager > Create Device > Virtual Device Configuration > Show Advanced Settings

But here the settings related to the amount of RAM were disabled

**The third method I tried was** to edit the Studio.vmoptions file and put this value in it (-Xmx4096m) but it still didn’t work.

**And the last method I tried** was the following trick, which made the virtual machine not work properly and crash

> I generated a Pixel 2 image in the past and those values were locked
> to match the HW default of 1536 MB, so to edit them I had to “Show on
> disk” (from ADV manager) and edit the hw.ramSize keys in hardware-
> qemu.ini and config.ini

**I have seriously tried all these methods and none of them worked! Does anyone know a solution!?**

*The amount of RAM memory of my virtual machines is 1536 by default and does not change  Please help me*

Comment: The IDE memory size is totally irrelevant for the emulator. The emulator is a separate process with own settings.

Comment: How can I increase the settings of the emulator to improve its performance?

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. When I start the Virtual Device Manager of Android studio, edit a virtual device and open it's advanced settings I can set whatever amount of RAM I want (of course limited by my system RAM). For 2GB emulator RAM your system should have 16GB RAM or more. Also make sure that if you still use Intel HAXM, because Intel HAXM has an own max RAM limit which you have set-up at install time.